# Mysql Query numbering groups rows

Tags: mysql

I looked for days for a way to show a compact continuous numbering for group rows. 
The products can be single type in the carton or mix together. Some of the carton markings are already printed so I cannot rearrange carton markings. 
I have this table:

```
+-----+------------+--------+-----------+
| qty | product_id |  Type  | carton_no |
+-----+------------+--------+-----------+
|  18 |        111 | single |         1 |
|  18 |        111 | single |         2 |
|  18 |        111 | single |         3 |
|  48 |        115 | single |         4 |
|  48 |        115 | single |         5 |
|  48 |        115 | single |         6 |
|  36 |        119 | single |         7 |
|  36 |        119 | single |         8 |
|  18 |        111 | single |         9 |
|  36 |        119 | single |        10 |
|  16 |        199 | single |        11 |
|  16 |        199 | single |        12 |
|   4 |        111 | mix    |        13 |
|   4 |        115 | mix    |        13 |
|   4 |        119 | mix    |        13 |
|   4 |        199 | mix    |        13 |
+-----+------------+--------+-----------+
```

The documents processor needs a view like this:

```
+-----------+-----+------------+--------+
| Numbering | QTY | product_id |  Type  |
+-----------+-----+------------+--------+
| 1-4       |  72 |        111 | single |
| 5-7       | 144 |        115 | single |
| 8-10      | 108 |        119 | single |
| 11-12     |  32 |        199 | single |
| 13        |   4 |        111 | mix    |
| 13        |   4 |        115 | mix    |
| 13        |   4 |        119 | mix    |
| 13        |   4 |        199 | mix    |
+-----------+-----+------------+--------+
```

The numbering are actually counting of total cartons for each product_id order by type, product_id ASC. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Group_concat see - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Check again your sample data and expected results.

Comment: What is wrong with the sample data?

Comment: The sample is fine the expected is not as I would expect first row should be 1-3,54 ? and so on

Comment: this is actually my problem because product 111 was added after a while again another box. So there are 3 boxes at first and then they added additional 1 box. The report has to be regenerated and it will start 1-4 as they are totally 4 boxes.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH 
cte1 AS ( 
    SELECT qty, 
           product_id, 
           Type, 
           carton_no,
           CASE WHEN product_id = LAG(product_id) OVER (ORDER BY carton_no)
                THEN 0
                ELSE 1
                END new_group
    FROM src ),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT qty, 
           product_id, 
           Type, 
           carton_no,
           SUM(new_group) OVER (ORDER BY carton_no) group_num
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(carton_no) > MIN(carton_no)
            THEN CONCAT(MIN(carton_no), '-', MAX(carton_no))
            ELSE MIN(carton_no)
            END Numbering ,
       SUM(qty) QTY,
       product_id,
       ANY_VALUE(Type) Type
FROM cte2
GROUP BY group_num, product_id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a7aeef8c33f5918168b09ae991b6bd33)

Comment: They don't accept same product_no twice in type single. The ctn 9 must be moved to top and it will be 1-4 for 111. :(

Comment: @Andy *The ctn 9 must be moved to top and it will be 1-4 for 111.* ??? carton_no=4 contains product_id=115...

Comment: they don't care about the printed carton_no . I put that column to make clear the difference between single and mix and you need the column for the mix type because many items has same carton.

Comment: We can redo the ctn numbers, but we cannot change the carton_no as it printed on the boxes. This is only for paper works for shipping.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH 
cte1 AS ( 
    SELECT qty, 
           product_id, 
           Type, 
           carton_no,
           CASE WHEN product_id = LAG(product_id) OVER (ORDER BY type desc, product_id)
                THEN 0
                ELSE 1
                END new_group
    FROM src order by type desc, product_id ),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT qty, 
           product_id, 
           Type, 
           carton_no,
           SUM(new_group) OVER (ORDER BY type desc, product_id) group_num
    FROM cte1 ),
cte3 AS (
    SELECT SUM(qty) QTY, 
           product_id, 
           Type, 
           group_num,
           carton_no,
           count(group_num) sum,
           LAG(count(group_num))  OVER () prevsum
    FROM cte2 group by group_num order by type desc, carton_no
)
SELECT CASE WHEN group_num = 1 THEN CONCAT(group_num,'-', sum)
        WHEN group_num <> 1 and Type = "mix"  and LAG(carton_no) OVER (ORDER BY carton_no) <> carton_no THEN CONCAT(SUM(prevsum) OVER (ORDER BY type desc, product_id) + 1)
        WHEN group_num <> 1 and Type = "mix" and LAG(carton_no) OVER (ORDER BY carton_no) = carton_no THEN CONCAT(LAG(carton_no) OVER (ORDER BY carton_no))
        WHEN group_num <> 1 and Type = "single" THEN CONCAT(SUM(prevsum) OVER (ORDER BY type desc, product_id) + 1,'-', SUM(prevsum) OVER (ORDER BY type desc, product_id) + sum)
        END numbering,
        qty,
        product_id,
        type
    FROM cte3
```

I think I solved the problem, but the code is working in Workbench, but not in fiddle. Any idea how to compress it more and not working in fiddle?